# Deleting cases that have an NA on variable1 ONLY if it also has an NA on variable2

Tags: r

Deleting cases that have an NA on variable1 ONLY if it also has an NA on variable2. I want to delete the cases that have both values missing together in R.

I've tried this code, but it is not working:

```
MyData2 <- MyData1[!is.na(MyData1$ variable1 & variable2), ]
```

I can see this is probably incorrect but don't have experience in how to code this properly.
Help appreciated!

Comment: `MyData1[!(is.na(MyData1$variable1) & is.na(MyData1$variable2)), ]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should close the brackets on the `is.na()` before the `&` sign, because this takes a TRUE or FALSE as input:

```
MyData2 <- MyData1[!(is.na(MyData1$variable1) & is.na(MyData1$variable2)), ]
```

you can also use the dplyr package which makes the code a bit more readable:

```
library(dplyr)

MyData2 <- MyData1  %>%
   filter(!(is.na(variable1) & is.na(variable2)))
```